# Evaluate html script stored in R object in R-markdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

In `Rmarkdown`, how can I implement/evaluate some `HTML` code stored in an `R` character object?

If I explicitly paste the code as plain text, it works as expected e.g. `<details><summary>Show/hide.</summary>SomeText</details>`.

However, I need to evaluate this from an R object; e.g. how to evaluate the content of the `Text` object: `Text <- '<details><summary>Show/hide.</summary>SomeText</details>'`?

Below is a reprex.

Thanks, Ahmed

````
---
title: "Literature notes"
output: 
  html_document:
    #code_folding: hide
---

<details><summary>Show/hide.</summary>SomeText</details> # This works

     ```{r, eval=TRUE, echo=F}
     Text <- '<details><summary>Show/hide.</summary>SomeText</details>'
     Text
     ## how to do the same using info stored in 'Text' object
     ```
````

Comment: I think I find a solution. `shiny::HTML(Text)` in the last line fixed this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `results='asis'` in the code chunk:

````
---
title: "Literature notes"
output: 
  html_document:
    #code_folding: hide
---


```{r, eval=TRUE, echo=F, results='asis'}
 Text <- '<details><summary>Show/hide.</summary>SomeText</details>'
 cat(Text)
``
````

Comment: This works Allan. Thanks. I was also able to fix it by using `shiny::HTML(Text)` but your answer is straightforward.